# Android Downloaded Files Reported Missing

Tags: android, file, download

We have built an android app that lets users download content from an http endpoint. The downloaded file is stored via `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` if the external drive is writable otherwise we use `Context.getFilesDir()` to store internally. In either case, we store the absolute path to a database (which could point to an internal or external file path) so we know how and where to find it later.

We've received a number of emails to our tech support saying that after they close and reopen the app that the files are gone. The people emailing with the problem don't have exact steps for reproducing but that has been their experience. No one on our team has been able to reproduce the bug, but it gets reported consistently.

The same people reporting the problem say that they are able to use the files when they download them. The problem is that when they come back to the app later they have to re-download them.

Am I missing something that the framework is maybe doing to delete the files on certain devices/versions?

I think some might jump to the conclusion that it's an external path issue. Meaning it gets saved there, and when they want to access it later the drive isn't mounted any more and therefore the file is "gone". We have a setting the user can `check` to force downloads to be saved via the internal method (which tech support has them try) `Context.getFilesDir()` so I don't believe that would be an issue.

I know this is quite vague but I've been getting nowhere now for quite some time. Perhaps some thoughts on storage in general would be helpful. How have you handled storing internal and external files?

Comment: did you ever solve this!? I've narrowed it down to 4.4.2 I think, but we are seeing this as well!

Comment: no, this is still an issue and the problem seemed to be spread across many versions and devices. We experienced this issue well before 4.4.2 came out.

Comment: Ah, thanks anyways. Did you ever find a workaround?

Comment: Nope, we have a limited amount of devices and were never able to reproduce the issue locally. If you've been able to do that then you could be on your way to finding a solution. Good luck.